# Need to embed the react components in existing jsp pages

Tags: reactjs, jsp

My webpack looks like this:

```
var path= require('path');


module.exports = {
  entry : './script.jsx',
  output : {
    path : path.resolve(__dirname,),
    filename: 'transpiled.js'
  },
  module : {
    rules: [ // rules rules
        {
          test: /\.jsx?$/,
          loaders: 'babel-loader',
          //use:'babel-loader', // use here
          exclude : /node_modules/,
          query : {
            presets : ['es2015','react']
          }
        }
      ]
}
}
```

I would like to embed react components into the existing web application made of jsp.

In addition to that I am not able to determine the location of transpiles.js.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

webpack doesnot embed react components into web application, it just bundles and builds result .js file, you should specify in page to include script file and have div element that ReactDom can insert created Dom-tree in it.

Comment: Thats fine , but without npm run , how will it render the react component. I was not able to find the react output file location as mentioned in the question